# How do I cast object to inherited class?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Say I have:

```
Class Tiger: XElement
{
    public Tiger(XElement t)
        :base(t) { }
}
```

And then I have an `XDoucment` named Tigers, how do I do things like:

```
XElement t = Tigers.Descendants("Tiger").ElementAt(0);
(Tiger)t;
t as Tiger;
```

The first one throws me an exception:
`Cannot cast 't' (which has an actual type of 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement') to 'Zoo.Tiger'`
The second one always return null.

What I am trying to achieve is to get the reference in the XElement and cast it as `Tiger`.
 Then I can do things like `XElement.Add` that can directly affect the reference in XDocument.

Comment: I really think you are using xml for the wrong purpose, you should have a tiger class and tiger list, you can always serialize this to xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use inheritance for this. The object returned by ElementAt is an XElement, not a Tiger, and there's nothing you can do to change that. If I give you a furry Animal that makes meow, there's no way you can make it a Dog, even though Dog is a subclass of Animal.

You can, however, use composition:

```
Class Tiger
{
    public XElement XElement { get; private set; }

    public Tiger(XElement xelement)
    {
        this.XElement = xelement;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
XElement x = Tigers.Descendants("Tiger").ElementAt(0);
Tiger t = new Tiger(x);
t.XElement.Add(...);
```

(Note that, since XElement is a *reference type*,

- `t.XElement`
- `x` and
- `Tigers.Descendants("Tiger").ElementAt(0)`

will refer to the *same* XElement object in memory.)

Comment: I was going to suggest this but he wants to directly affect the document,  and this will make a copy of information?

Comment: @Sayse: No. XElement is a reference type, not a value type. Thus, `t.XElement` and `x` will always refer to the *same* XElement object in memory.

Comment: Ah ok not properly woke up yet!

Comment: @Sayse: No problem, thanks for the feedback. Clarified this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before. Seems this is the only answer. I'll accept that.